# Xamarin.Forms Update Binding Label inside CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this label like so:

```
<Label x:Name="QuestionText" FontSize="62" Text="{Binding question}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,20,0,0" />
```

This is inside a CarouselView:

```
<CarouselView
            x:Name="Questions"
            HeightRequest="475">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="10">
                        <Label x:Name="QuestionText" FontSize="62" Text="{Binding question}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,20,0,0" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

And I am populating the CarouselView like so:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            questions = await webService.GetTaskQuestions(taskcategory);

            List<QuestionsClass> currentPage = new List<QuestionsClass>();

            currentPage.Add(questions[currentPageIndex]);

            Questions.ItemsSource = currentPage;


        }
```

And I am trying to update my text like so:

```
questions[currentPageIndex].question = questions[currentPageIndex].question.Replace("_", questions[currentPageIndex].answer);
```

I have even tried:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        questions[currentPageIndex].question = questions[currentPageIndex].question.Replace("_", questions[currentPageIndex].answer);

                    });
```

And still nothing, here is my class:

```
public class QuestionsClass
    {
        
        public string question { get; set; }
        public string answer { get; set; }
        
    }
```

How do I update a label inside a CarouselView?

**UPDATE**

I have tried with INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class QuestionsClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public string question { get; set; }
        public string actualQuestion
        {
            get
            {
                return question;
            }
            set
            {
                question = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                
            }
        }
        public string answer { get; set; }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string quetion = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(question));
        }

    }
```

Here is my label:

```
<Label FontSize="62" Text="{Binding actualQuestion}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,20,0,0" />
```

and here is how I am updating it:

```
questions[currentPageIndex].question = questions[currentPageIndex].question.Replace("_", questions[currentPageIndex].answer);
```

**UPDATE**

My class was wrong, this is the correct class and is now working:

```
public class QuestionsClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _question;

        public string question {
            get
            {
                return _question;
            }
            set
            {
                _question = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("question");
            }
        }
        public string answer { get; set; }
       
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are updating the questions variable (lowercase). Why don't you try updating Questions.CurrentItem (the carrouselview). Also I recommend that you change the name of the carrouselview to differenciate them better

Comment: Also, I would recommend creating a ObservableCollection<QuestionsClass> and bind your carrouselview directly to that

Comment: if you are trying to dynamically update the UI, `QuestionsClass` needs to implement`INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Jason how do I apply that to my class, I have seen examples but its super confusing

Comment: there are 10,000 existing examples, there is no point in me writing yet another one for you.   The one here shows everything you need to do in one page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: I have updated my question using INotifyPropertyChanged, still not updating

Comment: Ahhh I see what I was doing wrong

Comment: If you use ObservableCollection there is no need for IPropetyChanged. You can use it like any other list. Take into account that you should update it in a UI thread